# C++ optimisation levels uncovering latent bugs

Tags: c++, c, optimization

I have a scenario in which I have to update my server OS version and respectively the g++ version, what I discovered is that the code which was working fine start giving error on the new version (actually segmentation fault). Then debugging through the code, I realized there was something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char s[8]={'\0'};
        sprintf(s,"overflow");
        return 1;
}
```

the compilation was g++ file.cc -O2

Thus the optimization has lead to error as we are assigning the whole character string s, and there is no NULL termination. I just want to ask is it good practice to use optimization flag ON, specially when moving across different version of g++, as the error like above may fall in place due to bad programming practices earlier?

Comment: Bad code is bad code.  You just got lucky that it didn't crash before.

Comment: Or got unlucky...

Comment: Hardly ever a reason to use char arrays instead of strings in C++ (`c_str()` is good enough for most scenarios where you need a `const char*` and otherwise you can create a copy then and there) and this is another good example of why that is so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in the code; the fact without the optimization flag you weren't able to see the error is just bad luck.

Of course optimizers can have bugs, but current gcc produces bad code with `-O2` only extremely rarely. There is usually no reason to avoid common optimization flags.

This example is more of a reason that you should prefer to compile with a variety of options, preferably with some memory checking options and profilers than it is a reason to avoid optimization.

Comment: If possible, use different compilers, different platforms, and different libraries too.

Answer (score 3):

The error is the code. The code has an **Undefined Behavior** that it writes beyond the bounds of allocate memory area. You were just lucky/unlucky it was not showing weird behavior before and it just shows it now.

This is no way related to optimization flag usage, just a plain case of bad code exhibiting Undefined Behavior.

When you have a code with **Undefined Behavior**, all safe bets are off and You can be only assured of one law, the **Murphy's law**:

> Anything that can possibly go wrong, does

Answer (score 2):

The optimization didn't lead to the error.  A change to the compiler version and/or  compiler configuration (in this case maybe optimization maybe) lead to the existing error being exposed.

The good practice that you might be spurred to take on in the future because of this bug might be one or more of the following:

- test with tools such as valgrind to ferret out these bugs earlier
- avoid functions such as `sprintf()` that are easy to use unsafely in favor of using functions or classes that help prevent overflows, such as `snprintf()` or `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is faulty. The optimization is not the reason. `sprintf` adds null character at the end but there is no enough space in `s`.

So the fix is either declare `s` as:

```
char s[9]; //9 atleast!
```

Or, use `std::strncpy` as:

```
std::strncpy(s, "overflow", 8);
```

If you're going to use `s` as normal c-string, then use the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't understand your question--the error above exists no matter the optimization settings.  You've invoked undefined behavior--be thankful that the runtime was able to detect it reasonably gracefully, rather than (e.g.) formatting your hard drive.

The solution is not to avoid compiler optimization, it's to avoid invoking UB in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The question you ask is not so important -- your program is relying on undefined behavior. In that sense, the optimisation has identified a bug, and you should be happy about that.

Some optimizations can introduce errors (e.g. by assuming all floating point values are neither Inf nor NaN), but this is just not one of those cases.

Answer (score -1):

First - this code does nothing useful.
Second - you are writing 9 bytes into 8 byte buffer.
Third - Ascii strings must be suffixed with NULL as ending mark and there is no place to put 9th code in 8byte buffer.
Forth - Why would you need to place any string in local buffer and do nothing with it at all?